# Visual Studio transformou código em 0 zero

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mvc, view

Olá, estava trabalhando em uma view em MVC quando meu pc travou e reiniciou, porém a view ficou zoada, como se cada letra, espaço, caractere ficasse com o valor zero, conforme imagem abaixo.
Alguém já passou por isso?
Teria alguma forma de reverter essa situação?
estou usando o visual studio comunity 2017
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eita, parece que transformou seu código em hexadecimal. Chegou a tentar abrir o arquivo em outro programa, como `notepad++` por exemplo?

Comment: sim, quando abre parece que está em branco, como se nada tivesse escrito

Comment: O arquivo foi corrompido, não tem volta.

Comment: provavelmente foi mesmo, encerarei o post aqui. muito obrigado.